# Double try/except - bs4 best practices

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

Below you can find one of the methods I am using to grab some details from a job listing from SO. I don't know in advance if the page will have all the fields I need (hence the empty dict declaration on top).

Now, the only case in which I want the method to throw an error is in case of an `HTTPError`, in case it doesn't find any field I'd like to just return an empty dict. Using 2 different `try/except` blocks (one for each error type) leads to the correct behaviour but I am wondering if there's a more elegant/concise way to achieve this.

**get_so_extras.py**:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
imoprt requests

ua = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
}


def get_so_extras(job_url):
    """
    Get additional information from stackoverflow.com job listing page.
    Args:
        job_url (str): url pointing at job listing's page
    Returns:
        dict: a dict containing additional info about the job
        listing and company.
    """

    extra_info = {
        "company_logo": None,
        "salary_lower": None,
        "salary_upper": None,
        "salary_currency": None
    }

    try:
        page = requests.get(job_url, headers=ua)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        print(e)

    try:
        logo = soup.find(
            "div", attrs={"class": "grid--cell bg-white fl-shrink0"}).img["src"]
        extra_info["company_logo"] = logo

        # Salary information
        salary = soup.find("div", attrs={'class': 'mt12'}).span["title"]
        extra_info["salary_currency"] = re.match("[^\d\.\,\s]+", salary)[0]
        extra_info["salary_lower"] = re.findall("(\d+)(|\s-\s)", salary)[0][0]
        extra_info["salary_upper"] = re.findall("(\d+)(|\s-\s)", salary)[1][0]

    except Exception as e:
        pass

    time.sleep(3)  # be kind
    return extra_info
```

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the error you want using only one try, and multiple except.

For your snippet you could do something like this:

```
try:
    page = requests.get(job_url, headers=ua)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    logo = soup.find(
        "div", attrs={"class": "grid--cell bg-white fl-shrink0"}).img["src"]
    extra_info["company_logo"] = logo

    # Salary information
    salary = soup.find("div", attrs={'class': 'mt12'}).span["title"]
    extra_info["salary_currency"] = re.match("[^\d\.\,\s]+", salary)[0]
    extra_info["salary_lower"] = re.findall("(\d+)(|\s-\s)", salary)[0][0]
    extra_info["salary_upper"] = re.findall("(\d+)(|\s-\s)", salary)[1][0]

except requests.HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
except Exception as e:
    pass
```